# Как создать нейронку через Keras?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Имеется шесть числовых значений статистики киберспортсмена из HLTV.org. Как с помощью keras создать и обучить нейронку, которая бы на основании этих значений выдавала примерную стоимость возможного трансфера игрока. Не говорю, чтобы мне дали готовое решение, но хотя бы направьте на верный путь, куда копать, как правильно выстроить датасет и т.п.

Comment: Вы уверены, что для Вашей задачи необходима нейронная сеть? Судя по Вашей задаче, можно начать с менее жадных алгоритмов ML, при этом, вполне вероятно, что качество предсказаний будет достаточным. Другое дело, если нейронка - самоцель…

Comment: С каких, например?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, у Вас типичная задача регрессии для «обучения с учителем», то есть, нам дано: признаки (как Вы пишете - значения статистики) и целевой признак - цена трансфера. Надо обучить модель по признакам предсказывать целевой признак. Ройте, во-первых, в сторону библиотеки sklearn. Самые простые модели - линейная регрессия, решающее дерево, случайный лес, там их может пара десятков. А также могут помочь различные реализации алгоритма градиентного бустинга - CatBoost(Яндекс), LightGBM (Майкрософт), XGBoost. Для всех есть модули в Питоне и прекрасная дока.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо большое